# Estou com este erro em advpl

Tags: advpl

Estou com o erro da imagem quando faço a impressão do pedido de vendas no Totvs. Mas só apresenta este erro na terceira vez que faço a impressão, imprimo uma vez ok da certo, na segunda vez também, agora na terceira vez apresenta o erro.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da Impressão

```
#INCLUDE "FWPrintSetup.ch"
#INCLUDE "topconn.ch"
#INCLUDE "Protheus.ch"
#INCLUDE "TBICONN.CH"
#INCLUDE "rwmake.ch
```

User Function TSTREL()

```
Local cQuery   := ""
Local cNum     := ""
Local nTotal   := 0
Local nIpi     := 0
Local nIcmsSub := 0
Local nTotalF  := 0
Private oPrinter
Private oFont1
Private oFont2
Private oHGRAY := TBrush():New( , CLR_HGRAY)
Private lPreview
Private cLogo := FisxLogo("1")


RPCSetType(3)
If cEmpAnt == "01"
     Prepare Environment Empresa "01" Filial "01"
Else
     Prepare Environment Empresa "02" Filial "01"
EndIf

//RPCSetEnv("99","01")



    /*** FONTES ***/
Private oFont18T    := TFont():New("Courier New",,18,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont16T    := TFont():New("Courier New",,16,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont14TC   := TFont():New("Courier New",,14,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont14T    := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,14,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont18TA   := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,18,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont14TI   := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,13,,.T.,,,,.T.,.F.)
Private oFont11F    := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,11,,.F.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont13T    := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,12,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont13F    := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,12,,.F.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont10FA   := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,10,,.F.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont10F    := TFont():New("Courier New",,10,,.F.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont11FA   := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,11,,.F.,,,,,.F.)

Private oFont09T    := TFont():New("Courier New",,09,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont07F    := TFont():New("Courier New",,07,,.F.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont09F    := TFont():New("Courier New",,09,,.F.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont09FA   := TFont():New("Arial",,09,,.F.,,,,,.F.)

Private oFont7TA    := TFont():New("Courier New",,07,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont12F    := TFont():New("Courier New",,12,,.F.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont10T    := TFont():New("Courier New",,10,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont09F    := TFont():New("Courier New",,09,,.F.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont09T    := TFont():New("Courier New",,09,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont14N    := TFont():New("Courier New",14,14,,.T.,,,,.T.,.F.)

Private oFont10AT   := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,10,,.T.,,,,,.F.)
Private oFont10AF   := TFont():New("Arial"      ,,10,,.F.,,,,,.F.)

Private  nLin       := 350
Private  NSpace10   := 10
Private  NSpace20   := 20
Private  NSpace30   := 30
Private  NSpace40   := 40
Private  NSpace50   := 50



If oPrinter == Nil
    lPreview := .T.
    oPrinter      := FWMSPrinter():New(SC5->C5_NUM ,6,.F.,,.T.)
    oPrinter:SetResolution(72) //Tamanho estipulado para a Danfe
    oPrinter:SetPortrait()
    oPrinter:SetPaperSize(9)
    oPrinter:SetMargin(60,60,60,60)
    oPrinter:cPathPDF :="C:\TEMP\"    
EndIf



oPrinter:StartPage()
//oPrinter:Box (60, 60, 830, 530)

If cEmpAnt == "01"
oPrinter:SayBitmap( 50, 30, cLogo , 100, 100)
oPrinter:Say(80,180,"PIC-QUÍMICA E FARMACÊUTICA LTDA",                                         oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(100,150,"Morada da Estrelas, 65 - Jd. Nova Itapevi - ITAPEVI - SP",              oFont09F)
oPrinter:Say(108,150, "Fone: 11 4151-9000 - CNPJ: 03.421.909/0001-01 - I.E: 373.083.103.117",  oFont09F)
oPrinter:Say(116,150, "www.pic-web.com.br.com.br - vendas@pic-web.com.br",                     oFont09F)
oPrinter:Say(140,210, "PEDIDO DE VENDA Nº:" + SC5->C5_NUM ,                                    oFont14TC)
Else
oPrinter:SayBitmap( 80, 20, cLogo , 110, 60)
oPrinter:Say(80,80,"PHARMASPECIAL ESTEPCIALIDADES QUIMÍCAS E FARMACEUTICAS LTDA",              oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(100, 150,"Morada da Estrelas, 55 - Jd. Nova Itapevi - ITAPEVI - SP",              oFont09F)
oPrinter:Say(108,150, "Fone: 11 4151-9000 - CNPJ: 65.678.617/0001-06 - I.E: 373.083.103.117",  oFont09F)
oPrinter:Say(116,150, "www.pharmaspecial.com.br - vendas@pharmaspecial.com.br",                oFont09F)
oPrinter:Say(140,210, "PEDIDO DE VENDA Nº:" + SC5->C5_NUM ,                                    oFont14TC)
EndIf



oPrinter:Line(150,05,150,550)

cQuery += " SELECT  SC5.C5_FILIAL,SC5.C5_EMISSAO,SC5.C5_FECENT,SC5.C5_NUM,SC5.C5_CLIENTE,SC5.C5_TPFRETE,SC5.C5_MOEDA,SC5.C5_TXMOEDA,SC5.C5_PESOL,SC5.C5_PBRUTO," + CRLF
cQuery += " SA1.A1_NOME,SA1.A1_END,SA1.A1_BAIRRO,SA1.A1_CEP,SA1.A1_MUN,SA1.A1_EST,SA1.A1_DDD,SA1.A1_TEL,SA1.A1_CONTATO,SA1.A1_CGC,SA1.A1_INSCR,SA1.A1_EMAIL," + CRLF
cQuery += " SC5.C5_TRANSP,SA4.A4_NOME,SA4.A4_END,SA4.A4_BAIRRO,SA4.A4_CEP,SA4.A4_MUN,SA4.A4_EST,SA4.A4_DDD,SA4.A4_TEL,SA4.A4_CONTATO,SA3.A3_NOME,SC5.C5_CONDPAG," + CRLF
cQuery += " SE4.E4_COND,SE4.E4_DESCRI,SC6.C6_ITEM,SC6.C6_DESCRI,SC6.C6_QTDVEN,SC6.C6_UM,SC6.C6_PRCVEN,SC6.C6_XIPI,SC6.C6_XICMSRT,SC6.C6_VALOR,SC6.C6_XPROCLI," + CRLF
cQuery += " SC6.C6_PEDCLI,SC5.C5_MENNOTA,SC5.C5_XOBS" + CRLF"
cQuery += " FROM " +RetSqlName("SC5")+ " SC5(NOLOCK), " + CRLF
cQuery += "      " +RetSqlName("SA1")+ " SA1(NOLOCK), " + CRLF
cQuery += "      " +RetSqlName("SA4")+ " SA4(NOLOCK), " + CRLF
cQuery += "      " +RetSqlName("SA3")+ " SA3(NOLOCK), " + CRLF
cQuery += "      " +RetSqlName("SE4")+ " SE4(NOLOCK), " + CRLF
cQuery += "      " +RetSqlName("SC6")+ " SC6(NOLOCK)  " + CRLF
cQuery += " WHERE SC5.C5_NUM =" + SC5->C5_NUM + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SC5.C5_FILIAL = '" + xFilial ("SC5") + "'" + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SA1.A1_FILIAL = '" + xFilial ("SA1") + "'" + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SA1.A1_COD = SC5.C5_CLIENTE              " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SA1.A1_LOJA = SC5.C5_LOJACLI             " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SA4.A4_COD = SC5.C5_TRANSP               " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SA3.A3_COD = SC5.C5_VEND1                " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SE4.E4_CODIGO = SC5.C5_CONDPAG           " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SC6.C6_NUM = SC5.C5_NUM                  " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SA1.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '                     " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SC5.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '                     " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SA4.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '                     " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SA3.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '                     " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SE4.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '                     " + CRLF
cQuery += " AND SC6.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '                     " + CRLF

If Select("QRY") > 0
    Dbselectarea("QRY")
    QRY->(DbClosearea())
EndIf

TcQuery cQuery New Alias "QRY"

//Tratamento para campo data
TCSetField( 'QRY', "C5_EMISSAO", "D" )
TCSetField( 'QRY', "C5_FECENT", "D" )

//Tratamento para tarzer a descrição da moeda
_cMoeda := QRY->C5_MOEDA
DbSelectArea('SM2');SM2->(DbSetOrder(1));SM2->(DbSeek(DtoS(dDataBase)))
oPrinter:Say(310,iIF(_cMoeda==1,2200,2000),OemToAnsi('Moeda: '+GetMV("MV_SIMB"+cValToChar(_cMoeda),.F.,'') + iIF(_cMoeda==1,'',' - Taxa: '+TransForm(&("SM2->M2_MOEDA"+cValToChar(_cMoeda)),'@e 99.9999')) ),oFont09T)


oPrinter:Say(130, 435, "EMISSÃO: " +OemToAnsi(Dtoc(QRY->C5_EMISSAO)),                                                           oFont13T)
oPrinter:Say(140, 433, "ENTREGA: " +OemToAnsi(Dtoc(QRY->C5_FECENT)),                                                            oFont13T)
oPrinter:Say(160, 200, "DADOS DO CLIENTE ENTREGA",                                                                              oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(170, 10, "CLIENTE: ",                                                                                              oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(170, 50, +ALLTRIM(QRY->C5_CLIENTE)+ ' - ' +ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_NOME),                                                  oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(180, 10, "ENDEREÇO: ",                                                                                             oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(180, 55, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_END),                                                                                    oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(190, 10, "BAIRRO: ",                                                                                               oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(190, 45, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_BAIRRO),                                                                                 oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(190, 300, "CEP: ",                                                                                                 oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(190, 320, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_CEP),                                                                                   oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(200, 10, "CIDADE: ",                                                                                               oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(200, 45, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_MUN),                                                                                    oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(200, 300, "UF: ",                                                                                                  oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(200, 320, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_EST),                                                                                   oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(190, 400, "INSC. EST.: ",                                                                                          oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(190, 455, +ALLTRIM(TransForm(QRY->A1_INSCR, '@r 999.999.999-99')),                                                 oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(200, 425, "CNPJ: ",                                                                                                oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(200, 455, +ALLTRIM(TransForm(QRY->A1_CGC, '@r 99.999.999/9999-99')),                                               oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(210, 10, "CONTATO: ",                                                                                              oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(210, 50, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_CONTATO),                                                                                oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(210, 200, "TEL: ",                                                                                                 oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(210, 220, '('+ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_DDD)+')'+ALLTRIM(TransForm(QRY->A1_TEL, '@r 9999-9999')),                            oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(210, 300, "E-MAIL: ",                                                                                              oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(210, 335, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A1_EMAIL),                                                                                 oFont10F)

oPrinter:Line(215,05,215,550)

oPrinter:Say(225,200, " DADOS DO TRANSPORTE",                                                                                   oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(235, 10, "TRANSPORTADORA: ",                                                                                       oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(235, 80, +ALLTRIM(QRY->C5_TRANSP)+ ' - ' +ALLTRIM(QRY->A4_NOME),                                                   oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(245, 10, "ENDEREÇO: ",                                                                                             oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(245, 55, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A4_END),                                                                                    oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(255, 10, "BAIRRO: ",                                                                                               oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(255, 45, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A4_BAIRRO),                                                                                 oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(255, 300, "CEP: ",                                                                                                 oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(255, 320, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A4_CEP),                                                                                   oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(265, 10, "CIDADE: ",                                                                                               oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(265, 45, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A4_MUN),                                                                                    oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(265, 300, "UF: ",                                                                                                  oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(265, 320, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A4_EST),                                                                                   oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(275, 10, "CONTATO: ",                                                                                              oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(275, 50, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A4_CONTATO),                                                                                oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(275, 200, "TEL: ",                                                                                                 oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(275, 220, '('+ALLTRIM(QRY->A4_DDD)+')'+ALLTRIM(TransForm(QRY->A4_TEL, '@r 9999-9999')),                            oFont10F)

oPrinter:Line(280,05,280,550)

 oPrinter:Say(290,200, " DADOS INTERNOS",                                                                                       oFont14TC)
 oPrinter:Say(300, 10, "VENDEDOR(A): ",                                                                                         oFont10T)
 oPrinter:Say(300, 70, +ALLTRIM(QRY->A3_NOME),                                                                                  oFont10F)
 oPrinter:Say(300, 220, "COND. PGTO.: ",                                                                                        oFont10T)
 oPrinter:Say(300, 280, +ALLTRIM(QRY->E4_COND)+ '/' +ALLTRIM(QRY->E4_DESCRI),                                                   oFont10F)
 oPrinter:Say(300, 430, "TIPO FRETE: ",                                                                                         oFont10T)
 oPrinter:Say(300, 485, +ALLTRIM(QRY->C5_TPFRETE),                                                                              oFont10F)
 oPrinter:Say(310, 10,  "MOEDA: ",                                                                                              oFont10T)
 oPrinter:Say(310, 40,  OemToAnsi(GetMV("MV_SIMB"+cValToChar(QRY->C5_MOEDA),.F.,'')),                                           oFont10F)
 oPrinter:Say(310, 55, ' - ' +cValTochar(QRY->C5_TXMOEDA),                                                                      oFont10F)
 oPrinter:Say(310, 190, "PED. CLIENTE: ",                                                                                       oFont10T)
 oPrinter:Say(310, 255, +ALLTRIM(QRY->C6_PEDCLI),                                                                               oFont10F)
 oPrinter:Say(310, 400, "PROD. CLIENTE: ",                                                                                      oFont10T)
 oPrinter:Say(310, 470, +ALLTRIM(QRY->C6_XPROCLI),                                                                              oFont10F)
 oPrinter:Say(320, 10, "OBSERVAÇÃO: ",                                                                                          oFont10T)
 oPrinter:Say(320, 65, +ALLTRIM(QRY->C5_XOBS),                                                                                  oFont10F)
 oPrinter:Say(330, 10, "MENSAG. NOTA: ",                                                                                        oFont10T)
 oPrinter:Say(330, 75, +ALLTRIM(QRY->C5_MENNOTA),                                                                               oFont10F)

oPrinter:Line(335,05,335,550)

oPrinter:Say(345,200, " ITENS DO PEDIDO ",                                                                                      oFont14TC)

//nLin += NSpace30

oPrinter:FillRect({350, 05, 350+010, 550}, oHGRAY)
oPrinter:Line( 335      ,05 , 60,     05)
oPrinter:Line( 60       ,05 , 60,     550)
oPrinter:Line( 335      ,550 , 60,     550)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,05 , 350   , 550)
oPrinter:Line( 350+10   ,05 , 350+10, 550)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,05 , 350+10,  05)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,05 , 350+10,  05)
// Linhas horizontais
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,40  , 350+10,  40)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,260 , 350+10,  260)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,310 , 350+10,  310)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,340 , 350+10,  340)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,400 , 350+10,  400)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,430 , 350+10,  430)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,480 , 350+10,  480)
oPrinter:Line( 350      ,550 , 350+10,  550)

oPrinter:Say(357, 12, "ITENS",                                                                                                   oFont7TA)
oPrinter:Say(357, 45, "DESCRIÇÃO - PRODUTOS",                                                                                    oFont7TA)
oPrinter:Say(357, 277, "QTDA.",                                                                                                  oFont7TA)
oPrinter:Say(357, 317, "UNID.",                                                                                                  oFont7TA)
oPrinter:Say(357, 353, "VLR. UNIT.",                                                                                             oFont7TA)
oPrinter:Say(357, 409, "% IPI",                                                                                                  oFont7TA)
oPrinter:Say(357, 442, "ICMSRET",                                                                                                oFont7TA)
oPrinter:Say(357, 505, "TOTAL",                                                                                                  oFont7TA)

nLinha1 := 360
nLinha2 := 367    
nLinha  := 370

While !("QRY")->(EOF())


   oPrinter:Line( nLinha  ,05 , nLinha   , 550)

   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,05  , nLinha1+10,  05)
   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,40  , nLinha1+10,  40)
   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,260 , nLinha1+10,  260)
   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,310 , nLinha1+10,  310)
   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,340 , nLinha1+10,  340)
   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,400 , nLinha1+10,  400)
   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,430 , nLinha1+10,  430)
   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,480 , nLinha1+10,  480)
   oPrinter:Line( nLinha1 ,550 , nLinha1+10,  550)   
   oPrinter:Say( nLinha2, 15, +ALLTRIM(("QRY")->C6_ITEM),                                                                            oFont09F )
   oPrinter:Say( nLinha2, 45, +ALLTRIM(("QRY")->C6_DESCRI),                                                                          oFont09F )
   oPrinter:Say( nLinha2, 275, +TRANSFORM(("QRY")->C6_QTDVEN,'@e 999.99'),                                                           oFont09F )
   oPrinter:Say( nLinha2, 320, +ALLTRIM(("QRY")->C6_UM),                                                                             oFont09F )
   oPrinter:Say( nLinha2, 350, +TRANSFORM(("QRY")->C6_PRCVEN,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                      oFont09F )
   oPrinter:Say( nLinha2, 400, +TRANSFORM(("QRY")->C6_XIPI,'@E 999.99'),                                                             oFont09F )
   oPrinter:Say( nLinha2, 420, +TRANSFORM(("QRY")->C6_XICMSRT,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                     oFont09F )
   oPrinter:Say( nLinha2, 490, +TRANSFORM(("QRY")->C6_VALOR,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                       oFont09F )
   nLinha1 += 10 
   nLinha2 += 10      
   nLinha  += 10

   nTotal    += QRY->C6_VALOR
   nIpi      += (QRY->C6_VALOR * QRY->C6_XIPI)/100
   nIcmsSub  += QRY->C6_XICMSRT

   QRY->(DbSkip())

EndDo

nTotalF   += (nTotal + nIpi + nIcmsSub)

oPrinter:Box(nLinha1,    05, nLinha1+80, 550)
oPrinter:Line( nLinha+55  ,05 , nLinha+55   , 550)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha1+15, 15, "SUBTOTAL: ",                                                                                           oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha1+15, 90, +TRANSFORM(nTotal,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                                    oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha1+30, 15, "TOTAL IPI: ",                                                                                          oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha1+30, 90, +TRANSFORM(nIpi,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                                      oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha1+45, 15, "ICMS SUB.: ",                                                                                          oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha1+45, 90, +TRANSFORM(nIcmsSub,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                                  oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha1+60, 15, "TOTAL FAT.: ",                                                                                         oFont14TC)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha1+60, 90, +TRANSFORM(nTotalF,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                                   oFont14TC)

oPrinter:Say(nLinha+65,  45, "PESO LIQUIDO: ",                                                                                       oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha+65,  90,  +TRANSFORM(SC5->C5_PESOL,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                            oFont10F)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha+65,  355, "PESO BRUTO: ",                                                                                        oFont10T)
oPrinter:Say(nLinha+65,  390, +TRANSFORM(SC5->C5_PBRUTO,'@E 999,999.999'),                                                           oFont10F)       

oPrinter:EndPage()

If lPreview
     oPrinter:Preview()
EndIf                      

FreeObj(oPrinter)
oPrinter := Nil


Return .T.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que a causa do erro esteja no fato de você estar re-executando um PREPARE ENVIRONMENT, dentro de uma função ( U_TSTREL ) que está sendo chamada a partir de uma opção de Menu ou Browse, onde você já tem o ambiente / contexto de execução do ERP já preparado. Recomendo remover as chamadas de RPCSetEnv() e Prepare Environment, desnecessárias neste caso, e verifique se isso resolve o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado, retirei esta parte da minha função e deu certo não apareceu mais o erro....Muito obrigado